# Exception occuring Class 'UserSite' has no instance method '[]'

Tags: flutter

When I am trying to put data in dropdownmenu it's showing stack trace

> Class 'UserSite' has no instance method '[]'.
>       I/flutter ( 4454): Receiver: Instance of 'UserSite'
>       I/flutter ( 4454): Tried calling: 
>       I/flutter ( 4454): 
>       I/flutter ( 4454): When the exception was thrown, this was the 
>       stack:
>       I/flutter ( 4454): #0      Object.noSuchMethod 
>        (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:50:5)
>       I/flutter ( 4454): #1      _HomePage._dropDown.. 
>        
>        (package:truein_one/src/screens/my_visitors.dart:209:48)

Below I am providing code of my UserSite Model class

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
// final client = clientFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

List<UserSite> clientFromJson(String str) =>
        new List<UserSite>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => UserSite.fromJson(x)));

String clientToJson(List<UserSite> data) =>
     json.encode(new List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

      class UserSite {
           String clientSiteId;
           String siteName;

           UserSite({
              this.clientSiteId,
              this.siteName,
           });

            factory UserSite.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new 
            UserSite(
              clientSiteId: json["client_site_id"],
              siteName: json["site_name"],);

             Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
              "client_site_id": clientSiteId,
              "site_name": siteName,
              };
          }
```

And now I am providing the code for Ui part in which drop down menu has been implemented

```
Widget _dropDown() {
    return StreamBuilder<List<UserSite>>(
      stream: blocs.subject.stream,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<UserSite>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          list = snapshot.data;
          return Container(
              child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                  margin: Platform.isAndroid
                      ? const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0, left: 0.0)
                      : const EdgeInsets.only(top: 45.0, left: 0.0),
                  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      side: BorderSide(width: 1.5, style: BorderStyle.solid),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                    child: DropdownButton<String>(
                      items: list.map((items) {
                        return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          child: new Text(items["site_name"]),
                          value: items["client_site_id"],
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      onChanged: (newVal) {
                        setState(() {
                          dropDownValue = newVal;
                        });
                      },
                      value: dropDownValue,
                    ),
                  ))
            ],
          ));
        } else {
          return new Container(
            child: Text("Wait"),
          );}
     },
   );
}
```

I have data in my list for which I am providing an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArsIm.png)

I am not getting why I am getting this error. Maybe it is simpler problem but I am very new to coding and on flutter. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by type casting my class name

```
 Widget _dropDown() {
    return StreamBuilder<List<UserSite>>(
      stream: blocs.subject.stream,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<UserSite>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Container(
              child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                  margin: Platform.isAndroid
                      ? const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0, left: 0.0)
                      : const EdgeInsets.only(top: 45.0, left: 0.0),
                  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      side: BorderSide(width: 1.5, style: BorderStyle.solid),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                    child: DropdownButton<UserSite>(
                      items: snapshot.data
                          .map<DropdownMenuItem<UserSite>>((UserSite value) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<UserSite>(
                          child: new Text(value.siteName),
                          value: value,
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      onChanged: (newVal) {
                        setState(() {
                          dropDownValue = newVal;
                        });
                      },
                      value: dropDownValue,
                    ),
                  ))
            ],
          ));
        } else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
  }
```